# Spencer and Shelah zero-one law for Erdos-Renyi random graph $G(n,p)$

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

In Erdos-Renyi random graph $G(n,p(n))$; set $p(n)= (\frac{ln n}{n})^2$. We know that already Spencer and Shelah have proved that zero-one law doesn't hold for $p(n)= \frac{ln n}{n}$. Now the question is that will it satisfy for any exponent of $\frac{ln n}{n}$? Or again will not satisfy? (or may be it will satisfy for some exponents and for some of them not?)

I will appreciate your comments and possible solutions or any ideas for to start and prove it!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does this zero-one law assert?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  For $p(n) = (\ln n/n)^3$ the expected number of edges tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @ErickWong It makes perfect sense, since when there are no edges, there is a 0-1 law, albeit a fairly trivial one... to OP: read Spencer's -Strange logic of random graph_, a fantastic book that should answer your question (and much more).  It's fairly short and accessible.

Comment: @Graffitics Yes, that's what I mean: the "for any exponent" part of the question is trivial for this reason.

Comment: @ Erick Wong what he needs to prove is that to show $(\frac{ln}{n})^2$ is a threshold probability function for to having some property (maybe again connectivity!). But how can he show it?